# Relocating usage

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

"I am not considering **relocating**", I tend to answer this when I get an interview offer that I am not interested in. But I don't mean to relocate **geographically**, I mean I don't want to leave my company atm.

Does this make sense or should I use another alternatives since this is only meant for moving to another city/country? And if yes, could you please provide some alternative responses?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELL. I think your question will have more chances to be answered if you provide a concrete sentence where you would use this verb. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct word for moving to a new geographical area is *relocate*. But as you said, this is not normally used for moving employment without a significant change of geographical location.

If you were moved from one role to another within the same employer, that may be called a *reassignment*, but that could imply that it was involuntary rather than a move you orchestrated.

I'm not even sure there is a single word to mean a change of employer - I would just say "I'm not looking to move", as the context would make it clear you meant your employment.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes - ***to move*** (and even more so, ***to move on***) is a common idiomatic usage for *"moving" to a **different employer***.